# The attribute nativeQuery is undefined for the annotation type Query

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to create a Spring project.
In order to create query I used `orm.xml` file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm 
                                     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_0.xsd"
                 version="2.0">
  
    <named-query name="Student.getAllStudents">
        <query>SELECT s FROM Student s</query>
    </named-query>
</entity-mappings>
```

This is the interface [StudentRepository.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdRJj.png) in which this exception apprears:

> The attribute nativeQuery is undefined for the annotation type Query

I'm asking the help to resolve this issue knowing that the version of Spring is 4.0.2. Thanks for your help.

Comment: how do you import this annotation. where from? Maby this helps: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query

Comment: also, for the record, can you please quote your dependency for `spring data jpa`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help of **@T.G** and this thread [Setting up spring app with spring data repositories and mongo db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22118975/setting-up-spring-app-with-spring-data-repositories-and-mongo-db),
The caused problem is the version of `spring data jpa`.
--> So I move from `spring-data-jpa-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar` to `spring-data-jpa-1.5.0.RELEASE.jar`.As result, the exception disappears.